# How to skip Install ubuntu server page from the Install CD Customization of Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: customization, ubuntu-22.04

I'm customizing Ubuntu22.04 Installation CD, while Installing this I want to skip the below attached page (I want to display my customized page as the first page who ever is installing this).
As this is the first time I'm attempting this I'm searching the online resources but couldn't get a clue. Can any one point me to right resource or give some clue?

[image: This the page I want to skip]